# Remove existing polylines from google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have following code for mark few points in the world map and when click on each point randomly select two points and create polylines from that selected point to random two points.

http://jsfiddle.net/sux7eo3d/

```
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var locations = [
  ['Rio De Janeiro (GIG)', -22.808903,-43.243647, 5],
  ['Sydney (SYD)', -33.946111,151.177222, 4],
  ['Delhi (DEL)', 28.5665,77.103088, 5],
  ['Tokyo (TYO)', 35.689444,139.691667, 3],
  ['New York (JFK)', 40.639751,-73.778925, 2],
  ['Frankfurt (FRA)', 50.026421,8.543125, 1]
];
var flightPlanCoordinates1 = [];
var flightPlanCoordinates2 = [];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 1,
    minZoom:1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

    return function() {
      var p1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
      var p2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

      Point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(this.position.lat(),this.position.lng());
      Point2 = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[p1][1], locations[p1][2]);
      Point3 = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[p2][1], locations[p2][2]);
      flightPlanCoordinates1.push(Point1);
      flightPlanCoordinates1.push(Point2);
      flightPlanCoordinates2.push(Point1);
      flightPlanCoordinates2.push(Point3);

      var flightPath1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates1,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });

      var flightPath2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates2,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });

      flightPath1.setMap(map);
      flightPath2.setMap(map);

    }
  })(marker, i));

}
```

I need to remove previous polylines once I click on new point.

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: You are asking about polylines, not polygons.

Comment: I will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the two local polylines variables `flightPath1` and `flightPath2` global and then at the start of the marker-click handler reset their `map` property.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {    
  return function() {
    if (flightPath1!== null) {
      flightPath1.setMap(null);
    }
    if (flightPath2!== null) {
      flightPath2.setMap(null);
    }
    ...
```

On a side node, you've declared the coordinate arrays `flightPlanCoordinates1` and `flightPlanCoordinates2` global but you're not resetting their contents in the marker-click handler. Instead, you're adding more and more coordinates to the arrays with every marker click. To avoid that you should turn the arrays into local variables.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
    ...
    var flightPlanCoordinates1 = [Point1, Point2];
    var flightPlanCoordinates2 = [Point1, Point3];
    ...
```

Working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsh1mqbw/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an exact [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-remove) from Google Maps API v3.

You need to use this code in your function:

```
flightPath1.setMap(null);
flightPath2.setMap(null);
```

Comment: it doesn't help, I have tried this before, can you please show me where to add this code ?

Comment: @JanithChinthana You need to turn `flightPath1` and `flightPath2` into global variables first.